# How to fix rejected branch.io links on facebook

Tags: branch.io

When I pasted below URL's on facebook, LIVE once got rejected by facebook but TEST one works.

LIVE :

https://28x3.app.link/7AC36DC

TEST:

https://28x3.test-app.link/FFAC90F

Any reason why ?

See enclosed screenshots :

[error screenshot from facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f33A.png)

[LIVE and TEST links showing on facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYGob.png)

Answer (score 0):

This link points to content being blocked by Facebook.

To check this, go to this site:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
And then insert your link to debug:  https://28x3.app.link/7AC36DC

This provides the following message:
We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know.

So from here, please review the Community Standards page:
https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/

Here also is the FB "let us know" link:
https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/571927962827151